# Determine the Authentication method of a login page by using Burp Suite

Tags: networking, authentication

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to determine the authentication type of my router's login page. Right now I'm using Burp Suite and intercepting the request as soon as I hit login but the Raw information doesn't show the authentication method:

```
GET /post_login.xml?hash=131614284c1f558ac3c79eaded80a4e33849166b&auth_code=&auth_id=18D50 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
If-Modified-Since: Wed, 15 Nov 1995 00:00:00 GMT
Referer: http://192.168.0.1/
Connection: close
```

Is there something I'm missing? Am I trying this the wrong way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you expecting in terms of "authentication method"? It looks like a value (hash) is being sent to the webpage. My guess is that this contains your login information.

Comment: I am looking to know the web authentication method from the website